# Error creating function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

Trying to create a function in MySQL but it just won't go through.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `companydb`$$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `sf_utils_get_hm`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `sf_utils_get_hm`(sec INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(20);
    IF sec >= 3600 THEN SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%kh %lm');
    ELSE SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%lm');
    RETURN result;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It returns this error:

```
Query: CREATE FUNCTION `sf_utils_get_hm`(sec INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) CHARSET latin1 BEGIN DECLARE result VAR...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

For the life of me I can't see what's wrong. Line 7 points to `END$$` which...should be correct. I'm pretty sure my syntax is correct. Is it related to MySQL version? I'm using 5.0.67.

Comment: You are missing the `END IF` closing statement for your `IF`.

Comment: @RandomSeed Ah, can't believe I missed that. I rarely have to use END IF so I guess it just slipped my mind. Thanks!